# File Upload not working with HTML and DataSnap - FileCount=0

Tags: html, httprequest, datasnap, input-type-file

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form name="UForm" id="UForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/crcJurisUploadFile">  

Select a file 1: <input type="file" name="FileToUpload1" />
<input type="submit" name="btUpload" id="btUpload" value="Upload" />            

</form>
```

I try to read the uploaded file with the code shown below.  My results tell me Request.Files.Count = 0.  No matter what type of file I try to upload, the count is 0.

Why?

I have a simple DataSnap/WebBroker setup.  The WebModule includes

```
procedure TWM.WebModule3DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ...
  else if SameText(Request.InternalPathInfo, '/crcJurisUploadFile')
                then Response.Content := dm.UploadFile(Request)
  ...
end;
```

and calls

```
function TDM.UploadFile(TheRequest : TWebRequest): string;
var
  i : integer;
  HoldStr : string;
begin
  HoldStr := 'Content-Type=' + TheRequest.ContentType + '<br />'
           + 'Content-Encoding=' + TheRequest.ContentEncoding + '<br />'
           + 'User-Agent=' + TheRequest.UserAgent + '<br />'
           + 'File-Count=' + IntToStr(TheRequest.Files.Count) + '<br />' + '<br />';

  result := '<html><head /><body>'
          + '<h2>Request.Files</h2>';
    result := result + '<p>' + HoldStr + '</p>';
  result := result + '</body></html>';
end;
```

The Response displays

Request.Files

Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------291141107813480
Content-Encoding=
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
File-Count=0

Why is File-Count 0?

Answer (score 0):

You must add **ReqMulti**{for Multi-part Requests}  to your uses clause.  Was not included in the sample I was using.